# How should I integrate a response object input with code that needs a filepath?

Tags: python, python-requests, rasterio

I have some code that can take JP2 image files that I have saved on my computer and convert them into numpy arrays. The code looks like this:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

arrs = []

with rasterio.open('...image_file_path.jp2') as f:
    arrs.append(f.read(1))

data = np.array(arrs, dtype=arrs[0].dtype)
```

I have written a script that can use requests to get these images:

```
image_response = requests.get('https://image_url.jp2')
```

My question now is how do I merge these methods? just using rasterio.open(image_response) fails for me, how should I go about trying to accomplish my objective? Do response objects have an innate file-path? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I believe you can use `urllib.urlretrieve()` to download the image, then you can read it using `rasterio`

Comment: Thanks Anwarvic, I solved it a few moments ago with BytesIO, I posted the answer below in case it helps others later

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. The packages BytesIO and StringIO exist to do this. The complete code is as follows:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO

image_response = requests.get('https://image_url.jp2')

arrs = []

with rasterio.open(BytesIO(image_response.content)) as f:
    arrs.append(f.read(1))

data = np.array(arrs, dtype=arrs[0].dtype)
```

Thanks for your time!